# Show the online status of the current post's author

Tags: functions, author, transient

Is there a way that I can show the online status (Either online or offline) of the author of the post that a site visitor is viewing?

I imagine it's something to do with the Transients API (http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) ? Unfortunately that's one aspect of Wordpress that is beyond me.

Comment: Not an answer but something to bear in mind if you don't get anywhere with this is that [buddypress](http://buddypress.org/) offers that functionality. You wouldn't necessarily have to use the other features of it but is a very easy `check_is_user_online($user_id)` built into functions. If no one else can help I could have a look deeper into the functions and work out how it does it.

Comment: Sorry after just checking the functions I believe you do need buddypress for it to work as it uses the below line to work it out. `if ( bp_has_members( ‘type=online&include=’.$user_id) )`